# Discover which monitor has touch capabilities on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, touch, multiple-monitors

I have a two-monitor setup running on Windows 10 and my secondary monitor is a touch-screen.  I can detect both monitors with `EnumDisplayMonitors` and discover that there is a digitizer present with `GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER)`.  I'd like my app window to open on the touch monitor, but I can't find any function that tells me which monitor the digitizer "belongs" to.

In the absence of a solution, I suppose I could have a start-up sequence during which the user is asked to tap the touch screen, then my code could move the window to the corresponding monitor.  I'd just like it to be slicker than that.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`Win32_PointingDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pointingdevice) class can query **Touch Screen** (PointingType) information. You can try to see if there is any information you can used for matching the monitor information you get from `EnumDisplayMonitors` / `EnumDisplayDevices`, for example, like [`DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-display_devicea) to help you determine the touch monitor.

Comment: GetPointerDevices should give you that information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getpointerdevices POINTER_DEVICE_INFO  contains monitor handle and device type (POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE). There's also GetPointerDeviceRects that gives you where the devices are mapped to. Can't test it I don't have a touch monitor.

Comment: Thanks Rita and Simon.  Simon's suggestion seemed a tad simpler to implement, so I went with that first.  I matched up the monitor handle from POINTER_DEVICE_INFO with the one returned by EnumDisplayMonitors.  If you'd like to post that as an an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetPointerDevices function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getpointerdevices) give you that information. [POINTER_DEVICE_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-pointer_device_info) contains monitor handle and device pointer type in the same structure:

```
typedef struct tagPOINTER_DEVICE_INFO {
  DWORD               displayOrientation;
  HANDLE              device;
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE pointerDeviceType; // can be POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_TOUCH see below
  HMONITOR            monitor; // Monitor handle
  ULONG               startingCursorId;
  USHORT              maxActiveContacts;
  WCHAR               productString[POINTER_DEVICE_PRODUCT_STRING_MAX];
} POINTER_DEVICE_INFO;

typedef enum tagPOINTER_DEVICE_TYPE {
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_PEN,
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_PEN,
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_TOUCH,
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_TOUCH_PAD,
  POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE_MAX
} POINTER_DEVICE_TYPE;
```